# Use multiple mail service provider for a single domain

Tags: email, dns, aws-ses

is there any way that i can use 2 email service provider on my domain? Like i will **send emails** using AWS SES and **receive emails** on zoho provides mail service.

The basic thing is this that users come in to my websites they do stuffs like change password or anything else for that my system will use amazon ses smtp and whenever for ** recieving emails** it will use zoho email service. Because zoho gives us a panel to recieve emails or anything.

So any how i could use two email providers at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, because the configurations for sending and receiving mail are almost entirely independent. (Also, multiple services can be allowed for sending mail, although only one can handle receiving.)

For sending:

- SPF records in DNS. Those should be written to allow AWS, or perhaps both AWS *and* Zoho server addresses.
- DKIM keys in DNS. If DKIM is enabled in SES, then the AWS-provided DKIM key should be added to DNS. (But if you're keeping Zoho in SPF, then you should keep the Zoho DKIM key as well. As long as both services use different key selectors they won't conflict.)

For receiving:

- Just the MX records in DNS. Those should point to Zoho.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, it worked as you've said.